# WPF Designers : What is your design process?

Tags: .net, wpf, expression-blend, application-design

**I am going to totally re-ask this question.  So this is one big edit**

I was looking for a little feedback from WPF professionals, about their design process. For example, when I design a website, before I write any HTML, CSS, JavaScript,  I design the interface in Photoshop so I can I show the client a proof of what their site is going to look like.  Before I write any code, I choose the style, the color scheme, most if not all third-party graphics (stock photography) Once the client approves the design, I then start building it.

I was wondering what the equivalent would be for designing a WPF desktop application.  When it comes time to design the interface, select the color scheme, select the button styles, select any images that might go into it, is it common to create a mockup first?  Do you simply create all the graphics on the fly, at the same as building it.  Or is it more common to simply find a theme/skin online and employ it in your app?

And again, I know there is no right answer, I was just looking to hear what you all do.

Thanks

p.s. - 
I have Expression Blend 4, I am ok at hand-writing XAML (not just using Design View in Blend).  MY question is not about what tool I should use to build WPF applications, but about the design process.

Comment: If you come from the Print/web background then this http://www.microsoft.com/expression/ should be a good solution for designing WPF...

Comment: @Yahia, Thanks for the feedback, and sorry my question might have come across confusing...I have re-worded my question.

Comment: Maybe Yahia talked about expression design and not blend ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "there is no right answer" and [real questions have answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing your screens and assets in Illustrator, since you can import the vector assets later on. However, no miracle, and Blend is surely the tool to do the visual stuff (and esp. animations and screen behaviours).

Here's my method so far:

- Functional requirements and Information architecture on FreeMind (or Visio if you prefer)
- Wireframes and composites on Illustrator
- "Assets Board" on Illustrator (All what you want to import: Brushes (Colours and gradients), icons, complex shapes)
- Creation of images library (similar to web, with a pref for PNGs)
- Creation of Resource dictionaries (like CSS): Styles (esp. for fonts), Templates, Brushes and images, etc.

There is also the possibility to mock up a Proof of Concept or basic interactive mock up in Blend using Sketchflow. I'm not familiar with this but I heard it can be handy.

Illustrator can be replaced by Photoshop of course, I just think Illustrator is closer to what you should have in mind when you create XAML: there are Graphic Styles and Symbols tools that can be taken as equivalent XAML assets. You then know better how you will organise your production.

Answer (score 5):

For WPF applications, using Blend for designing the interface is the best way to go, as you can directly reuse the xaml from Blend into VS and you don't need rework. Although, you don't find too many designers having expertise in Blend(as compared to photoshop etc.); so, as of now design process is not followed that much(as in Web) in WPF world.

In case you are good at using other design tools and want to use them(like photoshop), then you can evaluate these tools for creating XAML from other formats -

> **[Visio Export to XAML](http://www.codeplex.com/VisioExportToXAML/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx)** An Add-in to Visio 2007 to create XAML
>   directly.
>
> **[XAML Tune – Convert SVG# to XAML](http://www.codeplex.com/XamlTune/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx)** A free tool that allows you
>   to convert SVG files to XAML files.  It automates XAML transformations
>   in order to improve design and code integration.
>
> **[Adobe Illustrator Export to XAML](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/)** A freely available plug-in
>   that enables Adobe Illustrator to export WPF and Silverlight
>   compatible XAML
>
> **[Adobe Illustrator to XAML Export C# Script](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=xamlxporter)** A script for
>   exporting Adobe Illustrator artwork in the WPF/XAML format. The script
>   is written in C#/.Net 2.0 using the Illustrator CS2 COM Type Library.
>   Although it is treated as a script in Illustrator, it is also a
>   stand-alone application.
>
> **[Adobe Fireworks Export to XAML](http://www.infragistics.com/design/#FireworkstoXAMLExporter)** The Infragistics Fireworks to
>   XAML Exporter is a Fireworks Extension that allows you to easily
>   convert artwork created in Adobe Fireworks to the new XAML format
>   introduced with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF). For those of
>   you with libraries of artwork created in Fireworks (like the
>   Infragistics Visual Design Group), this should be welcome news! You
>   can now reuse prior artwork, fills, and layouts in your new WPF
>   applications.
>
> **[Adobe Photoshop Export to XAML](http://flowlabs.net/psd2xaml.aspx)** Simple, free, open-source tool
>   for converting Photoshop .PSD files to XAML. Also supports limited SWF
>   conversion to XAML.
>
> **[Adobe Flash Export to XAML](http://www.mikeswanson.com/SWF2XAML/)**  A free tool that converts
>   Adobe/Macromedia Flash files to XAML
>
> **[SVG Export to XAML](http://www.wpf-graphics.com/ViewerSvg.aspx)** Another free tool that allows you to
>   convert SVG files to XAML files.

Taken from - http://www.realsoftwaredevelopment.com/the-complete-list-of-xaml-tools/

Answer (score 2):

Mockups are not just a good idea: I think they're mandatory if you have anything even moderately complicated and you want your customer to be happy.  I've seen two approaches which are both successful:

1)  Create an interaction demo using Sketchflow (which is now part of Expression Blend).  You have all of the power of Blend, but it's in a rapid prototyping environment.  You can then build the whole project and send it to your customer for review.  This is a good approach if your project is very interaction heavy.  [Check out these videos](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/resources/BlendTraining/Day.aspx?day=2) for a crash course on Sketchflow.

2)  Take your Photoshop comps and import them directly into Blend.  I haven't compared it with some of the tools akjoshi mentioned, but it certainly works.  The key is to chop up each screen into it's pieces and just import those.  You can then tweak each piece as it comes in, turn them into resources, etc.

Comment: I agree with most of the things Mike said, it holds true for the windows(WPF) world; but Kdub is coming from Web and the process he mentioned is genrally followed there(and it suits considering the importance of UX factor of web apps). In case of Windows, functionality is much more important and due to the restricted user base(as compared to Web) first priority is not always UI.

Answer (score 1):

We've used Microsoft Visio to do layout and get approval of UI before doing any Xaml coding.  I don't think that's too much better than Photoshop if you are really good at Photoshop.  For those of us who are not very good at Photoshop, Visio has a lot of tools that can align things, apply color styles, etc.  One person made a lot of stock objects and we opened his file to make copies so that all of our UI mockups looked consistent.

The funny thing is now that I am good at using the Xaml editor I find it quicker in many cases than using Visio. :-)